# Anyway to view image in newtab using ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm having a hardtime solving this, I tried using `a href="_blank"` but it doesn't display the image to a new tab. Any solutions guys?

```js
angular.module('selectExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
 $scope.newImg = [
        "https://picsum.photos/200",
        "https://picsum.photos/200/300/"];
  }]);
```

```css
img{
width:70px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="selectExample" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <div ng-repeat="image in newImg">
     <img  ng-src="{{image}}">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick

```
<div ng-repeat="image in newImg">
   <a href="{{image}}" target="_blank"> <img ng-src="{{image}}"/></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do following

```
<div ng-repeat="image in newImg">
   <img ng-src="{{image}}" ng-click="window.open({{image}}, '_blank');" />
</div>
```

Or

```
<div ng-repeat="image in newImg">
   <a href="{{image}}" target="_blank"> <img ng-src="{{image}}"/></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body ng-app="selectExample" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <div ng-repeat="image in newImg">
      <a ng-href="{{image}}" target="_blank"> <img ng-src="{{image}}"/></a>
  </div>

  <hr>
  <div ng-repeat="image in newImg">
   <img ng-src="{{image}}" ng-click="wopen(image)" />
  </div>

</body>
```

```js
angular.module('selectExample', [])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.newImg = [
        "https://picsum.photos/200",
        "https://picsum.photos/200/300/"
  ];

  $scope.wopen = function(image) {
    console.log(image);
    window.open(image,"_blank");
  };
}]);
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/fQZDCBeUE6jmqwdJU1YF?p=preview).

For more information, see

- [MDN Web API Reference - window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)
- [MDN HTML Reference - The Anchor Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)